# Why Chrome and Firefox have not the same behaviour with CORS ajax call with basic auth?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, cors

For the context, I am attempting to cross-site call an API wich need the user to be authenticated with basic auth.
The Tomcat (7.0.43) serving the API is set to allow cross-origin calls with authentication.

I am using jquery.ajax, passing the following options :

```
xhrOtpions = {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ressource",
        dataType: 'json',
        username: "user",
        password: "pass",
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      }
```

With Chrome (45), the request succeed, with Firefox (41), no request is sent and the error message is **Access to restricted URI denied**

To make the call work on Firefox, I change the options to applied what I read from the related jquery issue [on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2116) :

```
xhrActiveBuilds = {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ressource",
        dataType: 'json',
        username: "user",
        password: "pass",
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        },            
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization",  "Basic <encoded_credentials>")
        }
      }
```

This does not change anything for FF, still the same error.
On Chrome, there is now a preflight OPTIONS request sent, which is failing with a 403 forbidden response code.

Below the CORS filter configuration of the Tomcat server:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>http://localhost:1081</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
      <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: *"On Chrome, there is now a preflight OPTIONS request sent, which is failing with a 403 forbidden response code"* fix this and both browsers will work. Your server should support the OPTIONS preflight request.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @KevinB The tomcat server is already configured to allow OPTIONS requests: 
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>

Comment: then why is it giving you a 403 in chrome when an options request is sent? clearly something server-side isn't configured properly. Or you're not sending what the server is expecting. Neither of which we can debug for you.

Comment: [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) states that a request is **preflighted if it uses method other than GET**. In my case, a GET is used, so first options are correct (without beforeSend) and no preflight OPTIONS should be sent. So I still don't get why it's not working on FF with the first xhr params.

Comment: @KevinB No idea why Tomcat is returning 403 on OPTIONS. Has said, I  configured CORS filters and enabled OPTIONS like the [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) explained

Comment: the preflight may also happen when credentials are set. Not all browsers interpret the spec the same way.

Comment: The server must be configured to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header in its response, and in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header it sends in the response must explicitly contain the origin of the requesting server; specifically, in the case where you are sending credentials in the request, the  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must not contain the `*` (wildcard) character; instead it must contain the exact origin of the requesting server.

Comment: See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cors-check for the actual relevant requirements for this case given in the spec (which all browsers that support CORS do in fact conform to in the same way).

Comment: All the requirements you mention are matched. See the Tomcat conf I added for details. Moreover, as I already said, a simple cors GET with credentials works with chrome (as there is no preflighted OPTIONS sent). With FF I suppose that a preflighted OPTIONS request is sent systematically (but nothing appears in the network panel). But I agree with @KevinB that the server reject OPTIONS requests (suggested by the 403 response) and that point is a server side configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the 2 problems.

- **Server side**: I added *authorization* to the cors.allowed.headers
- **Client side**: I replaced the option with:

  ```
  xhrActiveBuilds = {
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ressource",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization",  "Basic <encoded_credentials>")
    }
  }
  ```

Notice that I've removed the username and password as their are causing the request to fail on FF because of jQuery implementation ([see](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2116))